# How can I display a message from ~/.profile?

Tags: login, desktop-environment, notifications

I want to display a warning message when a test in my `~/.profile` (actually, in another file that I `source` in `~/.profile`) fails, e.g.:

```
if [ -f /usr/bin/vim ]; then                                                                   
  export VISUAL=/usr/bin/vim
else
  echosomehow File not found
fi
```

The command should be portable and it should display the message as soon as possible when I log into a graphical session.

I've thought about using the `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to issue an `echo` command, but I'm not sure it is a proper way.

Comment: What's the issue with `echo "File not found" >&2`?

Comment: command not found `echosomehow`, are you trying to say `echo somehow file not found`. oh I can not work it out. Out of here, I am.

Comment: @Kusalananda I wasn't clear in my question, but I want a portable way to display the warning in a graphical session. Your solution works, but only on a tty. I had thought about using Zenity but discarded it because it's not really portable.

Comment: @ArchStanton Rather than adding more info in comments, [edit] your question and clarify it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Sorry, that was a dummy command :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `notify-send` to display graphical messages. DEs should have a notification area to show such messages.

> notify-send - a program to send desktop notifications

If you use `notify-send` outside of X11 or if you want to send a notification to another X11 server, you have to populate the `$DISPLAY` variable as described in the answers of this [question on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/647464/how-to-get-the-display-number-i-was-assigned-by-x).

Comment: It may also be possible that there are better places to do this from than from `~/.profile` (which is processed whenever a login shell starts).  The `~/.xsession`, `~/.xinitrc` or equivalent file may be a better place for a one off thing like this.

Comment: Thanks ctx, but I've tested it and while it works if I run it on a terminal, it doesn't if it's called from `~/.profile`.

Comment: Are you sure that `~/.profile` is executed? What happens if you run `bash ~/.profile`? Why do you want to use `~/.profile`? Did you try the files suggested by @Kusalananda ? Please edit your question, if you don't care for `~/.profile` but want to 'display the message as soon as possible when you log into a graphical session'.

Comment: @ctx "Are you sure that `~/.profile` is executed?" Yes, because the environment variables defined there are set. "What happens if you run `bash ~/.profile`?" The notification shows up (however, nothing is shown at startup with the same `~/.profile`). "Why do you want to use `~/.profile`?" Because I want to be warned when an environment variable refers to a nonexistent file, and `~/.profile` is where environment variable definitions go, to the best of my knowledge. (Are `~/.xsession` and `~/.xinitrc` executed on login to a tty?) I'm sorry for the late response, I wasn't notified of your comment

Comment: If you run notify-send outside of X11, you have to set the DISPLAY variable.

Comment: @ctx It's not a matter of running `notify-send` outside of X. My problem is that notifications in `~/.profile` don't show up at login to an X session. My guess is that it's executed too early.